# when i run this code it runs for crash , its curses library ,,,,,

Tags: python

when i run this code, trying to make the snake game (the line win=curses.newwin):

```
import curses 
from random import randint


WINDOW_WIDTH = 60 # number of columns of window box 
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 20  # number of rows of window box


#set up the window

curses.initscr()
win =curses.newwin( WINDOW_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH, 0, 0)
win.keypad(1)
curses.noecho()
curses.curs_set(0)
win.border(0)
win.nodelay(1) #-1
```

the out put is this:

```
 win =curses.newwin( WINDOW_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH, 0, 0)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_curses.error: curses function returned NULL
```

how can i solve this ???